# How to fix a MySQL Group By query?

Tags: mysql

I've got a table that looks like this

id, member_name, member_group, flag

member_group is a text value like 'admin','moderator','user' 
flag has a value of 0, 1 or 2.

I'm trying to figure out how to produce the following result from this table
Let's assume that there were 4 admins and of the 4 admins there was one 0, two 1's and one 2.

```
group, total, 0's, 1's, 2's
admin, 4, 1, 2, 1
```

Try as I might I cannot produce this result. I believe the grouping is confusing me.

My current query

```
Select
mem_group.group_name As `group`,
Count(mem_group.gender)
From
mem_group
Group By
mem_group.group_name
```

this only counts the total number properly, if I attempt to count individual instances of 0's 1's and 2's it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
mem_group.group_name As `group`,
Count(mem_group.gender),
SUM( CASE When flag = 0 Then 1 else 0 end ) as zeros,
SUM( CASE When flag = 1 Then 1 else 0 end ) as ones,
SUM( CASE When flag = 2 Then 1 else 0 end ) as twos
From
mem_group
Group By
mem_group.group_name
```

try something like this.

Comment: This almost works but produces 4 instances of the same count.
    Administrator  4  4  4  4

Comment: But I see where you're going with the case, changing Count to Sum should work ya?

Comment: @jauken I guess so, did you try with sum ? I edited the post, replacing count with sum.

Answer (score 0):

```
select group_name, flag, count(id)
from table
group by group_name, flag
```

will produce

```
admin 0 cnt1
admin 1 cnt2
admin 2 cnt3
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more precise with explaining the table, id is the member id which is unique to the member not the group.